# Creating/compiling C# scripts to executable

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

I have this problem, where I have my Windows Application (C#) that is basicly an application builder, just like Visual Studio can build executables from C# scripts.

So my question is, how does one accomplish to build executables with the c# scripts, directly from another Windows application that is already built from the Visual Studio.

**UPDATE**: I realized this was a duplicate, and the other questions that is similiar to this, had some interesting answers which I could use.

This can be deleted, if a moderator or anyone sees it.

Comment: See my answers to similar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748867/compile-a-c-sharp-array-at-runtime-and-use-it-in-code/11748925#11748925) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750585/c-sharp-load-a-text-file-as-a-class/11750639#11750639). You may want to add more details to your question, such as what you have already tried (or at least researched).

Comment: Create a proj file that includes the generated code, and invoke [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd393574.aspx) on it.