# Some questions regarding implementation of a scripting engine

Tags: c#, scripting, mono

Since this would be hard to explain, let me start with a Diagram:

[image]

So much for the theory, but how would I actually implement this? Is this even possible/feasible?

Some questions that come to mind:

- How would I actually load the scripts into Objects for the ScriptManager to hold?
- How do I expose certain functionality? I don't want them to have ultimate power over my program, only one Domain.
- How would the scripts even know about for example EngineClass? Should I do a using  in the scripts? Wouldn't that require to be copy of the assembly in the script path?
- I heard about MEF, is this possible? It seems more fitting for plugins.
- How do I even compile the scripts?

Of couse I understand you can't answer all of those or implement the whole engine for me. But I need pointers on what to do, I've been banging my head on this concept for a long time.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Have you looked at Lua? Apparently there are some libraries which allow you to use Lua from .Net. Depending on the functionality you need in your scripts this may be easier to implement and easier for your users, if they don´t have a C# / .Net background yet.

Comment: [LuaInterface](http://code.google.com/p/luainterface/), [Lua](http://www.lua.org/). Haven´t used it myself but afaik it works well.

Comment: @Lobo Thanks for the links. Sadly LuaInterface seems to depend on VisualC++ libary, but I want to keep everything cross-platform (Running on Mono)

Comment: There are engines for using Python, search for IronPython or JavaScript from .Net, i think at least IronPython can be used from Mono. Again, no experience myself.

Answer (score 0):

After some more researching I stumbled upon [What is the best scripting language to embed in a C# desktop application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137933/what-is-the-best-scripting-language-to-embed-in-a-c-sharp-desktop-application) and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/11/14/492458.aspx and it seems to do what I want with some modifications. How I didn't stumble on this the weeks before I don't know.

Comment: Beware, a lot has changed since 2005. Nowadays there are many solutions to the problem of embedding and restricting of additional code, such as MEF/MAF/CAS/Roslyn/Mono's C# compiler. That's quite a bit of reading :)