# want to create objects when I click a button and for every click new object should be created

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

Im making an application for my university in which i want to create object of student through customized constructor, but i dont know how to create objects on button click, i dont want to link it with a database, i want to create objects after application starts and all the objects would be killed when the application is closed.

Thanx Everyone

Comment: sounds like a HW assignment...

Comment: not an assignment but im curious how c# works

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i have tried what i know but i know very little, i know how to create object and pass them properties but what i dont know is how to create objects dynamically..

Comment: i want test newobj=new test("rehan",123); and for the next click automatically that should be newobj1 and so on

Comment: public class IAmACSharpClass {
   public int Id { get; set; }
}

then on Button Click, you can instantiate a new class..

`IAmACSharpClass yesIAm = new IAmACSharpClass();
yesIAm.Id = 99999;`

Comment: so thix method would create a new instance of that class at every click..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a button click - you will need `Event` handling and subscribe to correct events.

to create a new object:

`YourClass objc = new YourClass()`

to connect to a database:

you need to set up the `ConnectionString` correctly and access the database through `SqlClient` interfaces (or you can use `Linq2Sql` or entity framework or whatever!)

**--- edit after OP's comment ---**

You can create a new object with name and some id passing the name and id in a text box by actually compiling the source code and loading the assembly dynamically. This is ugly way to do in C#. But here is a way to actually compile an assembly in C# and then run it:

[What is the best scripting language to embed in a C# desktop application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137933/what-is-the-best-scripting-language-to-embed-in-a-c-sharp-desktop-application)

Comment: no i dont want to connect a data base, i know event handling too, but i want to pass name and id through text boxes which is not a problem, but at every click new object should be created, with the name and id i have wrote in the textboxes

Comment: Just grab the Id value from a Textbox when the button is clicked.  If you are using ASP.NET you have a reference in the .cs code to the textbox object.

Comment: gotcha @ aniket.. and thanx

Comment: give you a +1 because I have no idea what he is asking :)

Comment: @StanR. he wants to create objects with names that start with the data input in the textbox and an id in another number field.. so if the textbox contains "hello" and the number field contains `1` then he wants to create an object called `hello1`

Comment: no i want to create object if textbox1 contains rehan and textbox2 contains 3, the object name should be rehan3 and now the rehan3 must posess name rehan and ID or rollno 3 whenever called

Comment: and at every click new object should be created

Comment: hahahaha both of you mux be laughing at me.. im mad, the country where im, soon night gonna b over.. im sitting on my laptop since evening

Comment: @RummyKhan, the solution I posted tells you all about how to go about it

Comment: @RummyKhan hahaha and no, I don't think you're mad. Nor am I laughing

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what you're asking.

To create an object (whatever that means)

```
SomeClass classInstance = new SomeClass();
```

C# is a managed language which means you don't need to worry about killing the objects after the application closes, unless those object implement `IDisposable` but I have a feeling that is way above your scope for now.

Comment: `class` is a keyword!

Comment: @Aniket thanks, overlooked it :)

Comment: no thix ix not my problem, my problem is to set thix code behind a button on window form, i tried same code but that code only create one object but i want to create a new object on every click and properties are to be get from textboxes

Comment: it creates new objects each time it is called @RummyKhan

Comment: oh really, i never knew thix

Comment: and for their enquiry...??